# stop appending elements jquery

Tags: jquery

i am working with jquery and my problem is related to apped method

problem is straight forward

go to this link

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append

and click on append text .it keep on appending text everytime i click on button how can i stop this after one time

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<ol>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: W3schools is a terrible resource. Please stop using that. Instead, use MDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment on dystroy's answer, use:

```
$("p").html(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
```

That will replace the html contents of the paragraph element

**Edit following comments**

If I understand you correctly what you need to do is use the selector of the object you are trying to move in the append. So as an example:

```
$("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
```

will become

```
$("p").append( $('#theDivIWantToMove') );
```

Comment: @user2458516 Why not? If you give a clearer explanation maybe we can give you an answer...

Comment: take a example i want to append a image to div on click of a button but what is happening with my code that the same image is displaying ouside of the div when i click the button again .i want a solution such that on clicking a button again the image is removed and reinserted to that div

Comment: @user2458516 I am struggling to understand you... Now you are talking about images & div's? There are no images OR divs in your question. See if my edit above answers your question now...?

Comment: i want to use a code something like this but it is not working                                                                             $("#span1").remove.prev();
  $("#span1").append('<img id="theImg" src="k.jpg" />');

Comment: it's the empty tag what i was looking for problem solved thanks to all who helped

Answer (score 3):

You can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `click` :

```
$("#btn1").one('click',function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
});
```

Comment: i can't click on that button again without reloding the page actually i want the older text to be removed before appending the new one

Comment: @user2458516: if you want that behavior, then say it in your question. Dystroy is a perfect answer to the question you currently asked.